# Get object value based on conditions within nested array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested, array-filter

I have an array of objects called `orders`:

```
    const orders = [
    {
        "order_id": 47445,
        "order_type": "Wholesale",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "department": "Womens",
                "type": "Dress",
                "quantity": 4,
                "detail": {
                    "ID": 13363,
                    "On Sale": 1,
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I need to get the quantity when both the `order_type` (Wholesale) and `items.detail.ID` (13363) match.

I have so far tried the following:

```
const result = orders.find(item => item.order_type == "Wholesale").items
  .reduce((total, item) => {
    if(item.detail.ID == 13363) {
      return item.quantity;
    }
  }, 0);
```

Where `result` correctly returns `4`

My issue, and I'm sure I am missing something very simple is that when I have multiple `items` in my `orders` array, it fails.

```
 const orders = [
    {
        "order_id": 47445,
        "order_type": "Wholesale",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "department": "Womens",
                "type": "Dress",
                "quantity": 4,
                "detail": {
                    "ID": 13363,
                    "On Sale": 1,
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 56,
                "department": "Womens",
                "type": "Skirt",
                "quantity": 12,
                "detail": {
                    "ID": 76884,
                    "On Sale": 0,
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 89,
                "department": "Mens",
                "type": "Shirts",
                "quantity": 20,
                "detail": {
                    "ID": 98223,
                    "On Sale": 1,
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

The same

```
const result = orders.find(item => item.order_type == "Wholesale").items
  .reduce((total, item) => {
    if(item.detail.ID == 13363) {
      return item.quantity;
    }
  }, 0);
```

returns `undefined`

Thank you

Comment: Can there only ever be 1 "Wholesale" object with one item.detail.ID equaling 13363? Or can there be multiple (do you want to sum all quantities that match together?)

Comment: Exactly your last comment, thanks Nick. It needs to allow multiple and get the sum of all quantities that match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find` helper just returns the first match, so you need to use another helper like `filter`, like this:

```
const ID = 13363;

const result = orders
  .filter((order) => order.order_type === 'Wholesale')
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const items = curr.items.filter((item) => item.detail.ID === ID);
    console.log(items);
    // You can sum the matching items and then push them into the acc array
    const quantity = items.reduce((sum, item) => (sum += item.quantity), 0);
    acc.push(quantity);
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

This will return an array of matching quantities.

Comment: Thanks WIll, this works great, except there are instances where there are multiple orders with the Wholesale type and item detail id of (in this example) 13363. Is this possible? So that it would find the total sum of the quantity of either one or all that match Wholseale and Id 13363. As const item = curr.items.find((item)... is only getting the first match?

Comment: Yes, if it is possible you should change the find for a filter and then sum all the resulting elements. I edited the answer to give you an idea of that.

Comment: That is perfect. Thanks for the detailed answer and explanation

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.find()` on the orders array to find the correct order, searching for the first order that matches both the order_type and has an item matching the desired itemId (using `Array.some()`).

If this order exists, we can then find the corresponding item quantity using .find() again,

```js
const orders = [ { "order_id": 47445, "order_type": "Wholesale", "items": [ { "id": 9, "department": "Womens", "type": "Dress", "quantity": 4, "detail": { "ID": 13363, "On Sale": 1, } }, { "id": 56, "department": "Womens", "type": "Skirt", "quantity": 12, "detail": { "ID": 76884, "On Sale": 0, } }, { "id": 89, "department": "Mens", "type": "Shirts", "quantity": 20, "detail": { "ID": 98223, "On Sale": 1, } } ] } ] 

function findItemQuantity(orders, orderType, itemId) {
    // Find the first order with the right order_type and containing the right item id
    const order = orders.find(order => order.order_type = orderType && order.items.some(item => item.detail.ID === itemId));
    if (!order) { 
        return null;
    }
    const item = order.items.find(item => item.detail.ID === itemId);
    if (!item) { 
        return null;
    }
    return item.quantity;
}

console.log("Quantity found:", findItemQuantity(orders, 'Wholesale', 13363))
console.log("Quantity found:", findItemQuantity(orders, 'Wholesale', 76884))
```

Comment: why introduce null?

Comment: If we cannot find either the order or item, we do not know the corresponding value. Hence we return null, one could also return undefined..

Comment: ok, but if you want to handle exceptions you should use exceptions.

Comment: I don't think I would consider not finding the item an exception, right? It's perfectly possible the item is simply not present.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the use case but here you go

```
const result = orders.find(item => item.order_type == "Wholesale").items
  .reduce((total, item) => {
    if (item.detail.ID == 13363) {
      total += item.quantity;
    }
    return total
  }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = orders
  .filter(order => order.order_type == "Wholesale")
  .map(order => order.items.find(item => item.detail.ID == 13363))
  .filter(item => item)
  .reduce((total, { quantity }) => quantity + total, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const orders = [{
  "order_id": 47445,
  "order_type": "Wholesale",
  "items": [{
    "id": 9,
    "department": "Womens",
    "type": "Dress",
    "quantity": 4,
    "detail": {
      "ID": 13363,
      "On Sale": 1,
    }
  }]
}];

var result = null;
const result2 = orders.find(item => item.order_type == "Wholesale").items
  .map((item) => {
    if (item.detail.ID == 98223) {
      result = item.quantity;
    }
  }, 0);


console.log("result", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even create a function to make the search dynamic.

```js
const orders = [
{
    "order_id": 47445,
    "order_type": "Wholesale",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "department": "Womens",
            "type": "Dress",
            "quantity": 4,
            "detail": {
                "ID": 13363,
                "On Sale": 1,
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 56,
            "department": "Womens",
            "type": "Skirt",
            "quantity": 12,
            "detail": {
                "ID": 76884,
                "On Sale": 0,
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 89,
            "department": "Mens",
            "type": "Shirts",
            "quantity": 20,
            "detail": {
                "ID": 98223,
                "On Sale": 1,
            }
        }
    ]
}
];

findMyItem=( ID )=>{
var result  = null  ; 
const result2 = orders.find(item => item.order_type == "Wholesale").items
  .map((  item) => {
    if(item.detail.ID == ID ) {
      result = item.quantity;
    }
  }, 0);
  return result ; 
  
}


  
  
    
  console.log( "result" ,findMyItem(  13363 )   ) 
  console.log( "result" ,findMyItem(  98223)   ) 
  console.log( "result" ,findMyItem(  76884)   )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const orders = [{
    "order_id": 47445,
    "order_type": "Wholesale",
    "items": [{
      "id": 9,
      "department": "Womens",
      "type": "Dress",
      "quantity": 4,
      "detail": {
        "ID": 13363,
        "On Sale": 1,
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    "order_id": 47445,
    "order_type": "Whole",
    "items": [{
      "id": 9,
      "department": "Womens",
      "type": "Dress",
      "quantity": 4,
      "detail": {
        "ID": 13363,
        "On Sale": 1,
      }
    }]
  }
]

const result = orders.reduce(v => {
  return v.items.map(a => {
    if (v.order_type == 'Wholesale' && a.detail.ID == 13363) {
      return v
    }
  })
})
console.log(result)
```